# Facebook like button position issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a problem. I'm redesigning a website and I'm using HTML5 + CSS3. I'm making a bar with like and follow buttons. I normally handle those with an unordered list where the ul has a height of 20px and each child li element has the same 20px height and float:left. Then, I insert the div.fb-like and the follow button in separate li's.

The problem I'm having is that in Windows the like button moves 6px down on IE9, Firefox and Opera but works fine on Chrome and Safari (all browsers are up-to-date). I tried using jquery css fixing which worked fine, but then I opened the site on a Macbook on Chrome and it had the same problem with the 6px move.

Previously I had made another page where I used almost the same bar layout, but it was with XHTML 1.1 Transitional. For some reason it doesn't have that problem.

I am using the HTML5 version of the Like button.

You can see the demo here: http://yucatan.travel.zebradm.mx/prueba.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a vertical-align text bottom somewhere:

```
.fb_iframe_widget span {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Remove it and it will align

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work, I honestly had no idea lol. What I did was copy the definition and change text-bottom to top !important. It did the trick. Thanks again!